# Rails model associations - has_one or single table inheritance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, activerecord, model, relationship

I'm having trouble deciding between Single Table Inheritance and a simple has_one relationship for my two models.

Background: I'm creating a betting website with a "Wager" model. Users may create a wager, at which point it is displayed to all users who may accept the wager if they choose. The wager model has an enum with three statuses: created, accepted, and finished.

Now, I want to add the feature of a "Favorite Wager". The point of this is to make it more convenient for users to create a wager, if they have ones they commonly create. One click instead of ten.

FavoriteWagers exist only as a saved blueprint. They are simply the details of a wager -- when the User wants to create a Wager, they may view FavoriteWagers and click "create", which will take all the fields of the FavoriteWager and create a Wager with them. So the difference is that FavoriteWagers acts as only as a storage for Wager, and also includes a name specified by the user.

I read up on STI, and it seems that a lot of examples have multiple subclassing - eg. Car, Motorcycle, Boat for a "Vehicle" class. Whereas I won't have multiple subclasses, just one (FavoriteWager < Wager). People have also said to defer STI until I can have more classes. I can't see myself subclassing the Wagers class again anytime soon, so that's why I'm hesitant to do STI.

On the other hand, has_one doesn't seem to capture the relationship correctly. Here is an example:

```html
Class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :favorite_wagers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :wagers, dependent: destroy
end

Class FavoriteWager < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :wager
  belongs_to: user, index: true, foreign_key: true
end

Class Wager < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :favorite_wager, optional: true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I've also thought about just copying the fields directly, but that's not very DRY. Adding an enum with a "draft" option seems too little, because I might need to add more fields in the future (eg. time to auto-create), at which point it starts to evolve into something different. Thoughts on how to approach this?

Comment: Can't you just add an enum to the model that marks it as a draft? It sounds like you're overthinking this

Comment: I think you have your associations backwards. It seems to me that a FavoriteWager `belongs_to :wager` and Wager `has_one :favorite_wager`.

Comment: @hashrocket thanks for input. Only issue I have with this is that a wager won't always have a favorite_wager. Most of the time it won't because it is created without intent of being saved for future use. Eg. User creates wager, and other users can see it and accept it. A wager CAN BE a favorite wager if the user decides that they will create this wager often. If they create a favorite_wager, it just saves the fields of a wager, + a name for favorite_wager. Then upon creation, rails will create a wager based off those saved details. Does that clarify things?

Comment: Hi @max how would I deal with the favorite_wager's name? Would I make it an optional field on the wagers class? And to get all the user's favorite_wagers, I would have to define a method that gets all wagers with "draft" status I suppose. It feels weird because though these two models are very similar, they are still a separate concept. And what if I have to add more fields to the FavoriteWagers class in the future? It seems that there will be an increasing difference and the enum style won't cut it.

Comment: I can’t recall off hand if `has_one` is mandatory, but if it is, you can set `optional: true`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do a join table like:

```
Class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :favorite_wagers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :wagers, through: :favorite_wagers
end


Class FavoriteWager < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :wager, index: true, foreign_key: true
  belongs_to :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
end

Class Wager < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :favorite_wager, dependent: destroy
  has_one :user, through: :favorite_wager
end
```

Your `FavoriteWager` would have the following fields:

```
|user_id|wager_id|name|
```

That way you can access it like:

```
some_user.favorite_wagers
=> [#<FavoriteWager:0x00007f9adb0fa2f8...

some_user.favorite_wagers.first.name
=> 'some name'

some_user.wagers.first.amount
=> '$10'

some_user.wagers.first.favorite_wager.name
=> 'some name'
```

which returns an array of favorite wagers. If you only want to have ONE favorite wager per user you can tweak it to limit that. But this gives you the ability to have wagers and users tied together as favorites with a name attribute. I don't quite understand your use case of 'a live wager never has a favorite' but that doesn't matter, you can tweak this to suit your needs.

Comment: As I understand it, :through is whatever the middleman is. So to draw a parallel, Users might have Groups through GroupMemberships. Users can't have a Group without specifying GroupMembership. In my case, Users create Wagers, which other users can accept. You don't need a FavoriteWager to create a Wager. Wagers are stand-alone from FavoriteWagers, ie. they shouldn't know that FavoriteWagers exist. FavoriteWagers exist only as a saved blueprint -- when the User wants to act on that blueprint, they may create a Wager out of the details of the FavoriteWager. Lmk if that clarifies things.

Comment: It helps. You should really edit your question to have more info like that. It is very difficult for people to answer a question when they have to guess at your use cases. It seems like you have three concepts: a proposed wager, a wager that has been accepted, and a wager that has been saved as a favorite. You might want to expand on that in your question.

Comment: does that change your answer?

Comment: sometimes it's hard to keep it brief and informative, such that I get enough information across and don't just have a wall of text that will turn answerers away. I edited the question to try to make the best of both sides.

Comment: To really give you a useful answer I think I would need to see not just the models but the DB schema and some more detailed mapping of how you are using all of this. Your question is a bid broad for StackOverflow. You really need to expand your question with more models and code.

Comment: I see. There's a lot to include and I'm not sure what may be helpful and what may just be useless info. I think I'll go for it and try STI and if it doesn't work, try something different until it works. Shaking off the analysis paralysis.

Comment: Don't forget you could use a PORO if you wanted to break out some code into a separate class but not have it be an ActiveModel.